# Darwin OS is discountinued, but can the original source code still be found?

Tags: unix, operating-system

I have searched all around google for the originial source for the last release of Darwin OS that apple release. What I found was different OSes such as GNU Darwin and pureDarwin that were based on the Darwin Source code. Is there any place I can fork the original Darwin Source Code, or does it simply extinct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [Apple's open source site](http://www.opensource.apple.com/). The latest (10.7.4) kernel is [xnu-1699.26.8](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1699.26.8/), other [source packages for 10.7.4](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-1074/) are available too. Remember that not all parts of Mac OS X are open source. You will not be able to build the complete system by source.

Apple provides information about [how to build and debug a kernel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/build/build.html) in their developer library. Besides the devolper library you may find the book *[Mac OS X Internals](http://flylib.com/books/en/3.126.1.1/1/). A Systems Approach.* by Amit Singh useful.

Comment: So would I actually have to downloads these one by one and compile it?

Comment: @user1478731 yes. There is no `make world` to build the entire OS because not all of it is open sourced.

Comment: so in addition to to downloading everything one by one, I have to compile them separately!! So how will this form Darwin!

Comment: @ElHombre These parts do not form a working operating system. These are just the open source parts of Mac OS X (or iOS, which is also based on Darwin).

Comment: ok, thanks. So basically, its not possible to form a working Darwin OS anymore

Comment: @ElHombre Apple surely can and does build Mac OS X and iOS. They just don't share all of their source code with us. I think (not sure) you _can_ build a working (but very basic) Darwin OS from source. It will be something very minimalistic and very different from a Mac OS X or Ubuntu Linux install disc...

Comment: I don't need anything complex, just something to build upon, So if it is possible (which was were I was trying to point my question to) is there any way I can find info to build this basic system?

Comment: @ElHombre I added two links to my answer.

Comment: Ill see what this guide help me accomplish. Thanks =)

Comment: Ok, So after reading Apple's Guide, my ultimate question for it is, is that a kernel that can boot of another machine, or will it replace my current one on my mac?

Comment: It is a standard kernel that will run on any mac that is supported by Lion. Don't do it until you completely understand the consequences. Especially don't do it on your only computer. At least do a complete backup!

Comment: so it won't replace my kernel?

Comment: Since the consequences are severe, would it be possible to do it in a virtual machine running OSX

Comment: Yes, a virtual machine is a good idea. The kernel is not automatically replaced, in a normal system your kernel is the file `/mach_kernel`.

Comment: Im sorry If I am bothering you but I have a final question. The latest kernels as well as any previous ones can only be booted on a mac?

Comment: Yes, Apple's version of Darwin is supposed to run on Apple hardware only. To run on a PC you would need to use another bootstrap scheme and use different device drivers. People who run Hackintoshes do just that.

Answer (score 0):

Source code does exist, and if you know how you can assemble a open-source Darwin-based OS that can (partially) run OS X programs. However, since Apple did not provide all required sources for a working OS, you may need to seek for open-sourced replacements, including:

- **X Window System** replacing WindowManager, as the resulting system will be just another plain UNIX system, using GUI would require that.
- **GNUstep** as a replacing Cocoa and CoreFoundation implementation. GNUstep follows the development of Cocoa before there was Cocoa - it started in Mr. Jobs's NeXT times.
- **WindowMaker** as a replacing Dock, and **GWorkspace** as a replacing Finder. This will make the resulting system's look and feel like that of Mr. Job's NeXT before it became OS X.
- **ProjectCenter** and **Gorm** as replacing **Xcode** and **Interface Builder**. These are development tools which is going to be heavily used on that platform.

And some OS X apps are known to be able to be ported after a recompile or simple copied over (essentially any app that does not depend on Core* technologies or CoreFoundation, which are missing/not complete in GNUstep):

- **TextEdit** (from OS X 10.6 or older) GNUstep used to ship a version of TextEdit ported from NeXT. With recent library developments, the version from 10.6 can be used instead.